# Is a function using template for data type not supposed to return long long int?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to c++ and I've written a function which takes a and b as input and returns a raised to the power of b. I used templates for the function return data type and data type for a. but it fails to return the correct result for large numbers. I tried calculating pow(2,50) and it returns 0.

```cpp
template <class numeric_type>
numeric_type pow(numeric_type a, int b) {
    numeric_type result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        result *= a;
        cout << result << i << endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And inside the main:

```cpp
long long int powered = pow(2, 50);
cout << powered;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template arguments are deduced from function arguments being passed (but not return type); so given `pow(2, 50);`, `numeric_type` is deduced as `int`.

You can specify `numeric_type` explicitly,

```
auto powered = pow<long long int>(2, 50); // specify numeric_type as long long int explicitly
```

or add an explicit conversion on `2` to make it a `long long int`.

```
auto powered = pow(static_cast<long long int>(2), 50); // numeric_type is deduced as long long int
```

Comment: @ArianHassani Then I suggest pressing the green tick on the left of this answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: `2LL` would be shorter than `static_cast<long long int>(2)`.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, that wont work. The numeric type of '2' is int. Use '2LL' for a long long int. The reason this isn't working is because 2^50 is too big to store within an integer (it's a 32bit number, but you would need 51bits to store 2^50)

`auto powered = pow(2LL, 50);`